# React native windows mobile support

Tags: windows, xamarin, react-native, cross-platform

I will start to develop a mobile app using a cross platform.The app has multiple pie charts and graphs. App needs to run on Android, iOS and Windows platform. I am evaluating 2 options for cross platform:
1. React Native
2. Xamarin

I've gone through the documentation for RN windows platform(https://github.com/ReactWindows/react-native-windows)
It appears that React Native has limited support for Windows app development as of now.

Has anybody developed a full-fledged windows mobile app using React Native? If there are blockers for React Native windows, I would choose Xamarin as a development Platform.

Can someone please guide me regarding this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

React Native Windows has several sample applications, namely Facebook's own f8 app that prove it works well on Windows 10 mobile, desktop, or even Xbox One and Xbox Series S/X consoles. If you run into specific issues, you can file them in the GitHub project.